# what datatype json object read from a socket stream into c or c++

Tags: c++, c, json, sockets

I'm implementing some code to parse a JSON object read from a socket and I am playing with both a c and c++ server programme (both as I haven't completely got my head around boost.asio yet).
As far as I can see, with c socket API code I'm using, the data from the stream is being read into a char [] array called buffer.

I want to adapt this code from jansson to parse the JSON object and extract the key, value pairs:
    const char *key;
    json_t *value;

```
void *iter = json_object_iter(obj);
while(iter)
{
    key = json_object_iter_key(iter);
    value = json_object_iter_value(iter);
    /* use key and value ... */
iter = json_object_iter_next(obj, iter);
}
```

This is the function to read from the socket:

```
void read_socket (int sock)
{
   int n;
   char buffer[256];
   bzero(buffer,256);
   n = read(sock,buffer,255);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
   printf("Data received: %s\n",buffer);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
}
```

My question is, is it raw character data stored in the buffer and if I pass it to the jansson function, will it be a JSON object, or is there something else I need to do, such as convert back into a JSON object from the stream of data read from the socket?
Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, a few weeks ago I knew nothing about sockets and I'm trying to send data between bash and c or c++, on a local system as part of a programme I'm developing.

Comment: I never got why socket API uses ``char`` and not ``unsigned char`` as their buffer type. That aside, as you program both endpoints of the communication you should know what you send. It might be a good idea to frame your raw data with some small application layer protocol header, which can be as simple as the length info about the next JSON message. ``...<length><message><length><message>...``.  Your receive code then has a loop and reads <length> first, then <length> bytes etc. Due to transport unit sizes, the chunks you read might not correspond to chunks you sent.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I was going to embed some python in my bash script to create and a JSON object to send to a socket.
How does the char being signed or unsigned affect the buffer type (I know what unsigned is), what difference does that make?
Re length, I've seen some examples of code doing that I think. So I should send a stream containing "message length", followed by the JSON object, each time I write to the socket?
But once its read into the char array, can I just pass it to the jansson function? Or do I need to convert it back into JSON first?

Comment: I guess after receiving your JSON message as a string, you would call ``json_loads()`` or ' ' json_loadb()' '  and then decode it as needed.